# Hit test or event on Firemonkey Tlistboxgroupheader

Tags: events, header, listbox, firemonkey

I'm trying to create a listbox that collapse/expand the items until they are needed, but I can't find an event to trigger on the listboxgroupheader click.

I added a button positioned on a Listbox header to collapse all the items under it manually, as it seems that there are no easy expand/collapse options for items under a header.  Nothing worked, and on closer inspection it seems like the OnClick event on the ListboxGroupHeader is not triggering.  In fact, I can't seem to trigger any event (mouse down, etc) from the listboxgroupheader.

To replicate:

1. Add a listbox
2. Add a couple of listboxitems as well as some
   listboxgroupheaders using the Items editor.
3. Goto Listbox header, and add OnClick event
4. I put a breakpoint on the sleep(10) code, just to see if the event fires, but I never reach it

```
    procedure TFrame_Logging.listboxgroupheaderClick(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      sleep(10);  //I have a breakpoint here that is never reached
    end;
```

From what I can see, the Listboxgroupheader does not have any methods for events?  Am I missing something, or is the OnClick of the listboxgroupheader different from other components?

Comment: You must be doing something wrong, but as you did not provide a [mre], it is impossible to say what exactly. Please provide an example of your problem, including both `.pas` file and `.fmx` file

Answer (score 0):

In the mean time I tested with the following, that hides / shows items of a clicked header.

```
type
  TForm5 = class(TForm)
    ListBox1: TListBox;
    ListBoxGroupHeader1: TListBoxGroupHeader;
    ListBoxGroupHeader2: TListBoxGroupHeader;
    ListBoxGroupHeader3: TListBoxGroupHeader;
    ListBoxItem1: TListBoxItem;
    ListBoxItem2: TListBoxItem;
    ListBoxItem3: TListBoxItem;
    ListBoxItem4: TListBoxItem;
    ListBoxItem5: TListBoxItem;
    ListBoxItem6: TListBoxItem;
    ListBoxItem7: TListBoxItem;
    ListBoxItem8: TListBoxItem;
    ListBoxItem9: TListBoxItem;
    ListBoxGroupHeader4: TListBoxGroupHeader;
    procedure ListBoxGroupHeaderClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

implementation
{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm5.ListBoxGroupHeaderClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  sleep(10);

  with TListBoxGroupHeader(Sender) do
  begin
    var i := index + 1;
    repeat
      if ListBox1.ItemByIndex(i) is TListBoxGroupHeader then Exit;
      ListBox1.ItemByIndex(i).Visible := not ListBox1.ItemByIndex(i).Visible;
      i := i + 1;
    until i > (ListBox1.Items.Count-1);
  end;

end;
```

[image]

In this picture the `ListBoxGroupHeader2` items are contracted (i.e. hidden).

Also the added `sleep(10)` with a breakpoint works as expected.

So, I can't really think of any reason why your test doesn't succeed. Which version are you using? My tests I did with `Delphi 10.4 CE`.

---

Came to think of this expression of yours:

> From what I can see, the `Listboxgroupheader` does not have any methods for events?

All items of a `TListBox` have a number of events, from which you select the ones you need by double-clicking in the `Object Inspector` **`events`** listing, to let the IDE create the event stub. In this stub you then add your code. But surely you knew this fundamental feature of Delphi IDE already?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Tom. Your answer pointed me to a solution, even though it was not what I expected.  When asking the question, I did not replicate the problem in a small demo app, and when I did, I could not reproduce it because the event fired every time.  I then tried the event on a different listboxgroupheader in the same master application, which worked... so now I was really stumped.  The event on the specific listboxgroupheader I used when asking the question still did not work though.  I simply deleted it and added another one, and voila... all worked as expected.  I still do not know why the event did not fire initially though, but deleting and replacing wasn't too difficult.